# How can I access hot questions only for a particular tag?

Tags: support, tags, hot-questions

When I visit the homepage of Stack Overflow, there are various tabs according to which the questions may be listed:

[image: question listing tab on homepage]

These contains the options to list the questions according to their hotness on the site:

- **hot** lists questions which were posted within the last day or so
- **week** lists the questions which were posted within the last week or so
- **month** lists the questions which were posted within the last month or so

However, Stack Overflow being so vast, it applies the hotness to all the questions across all the tags. Having a tag as a favorite doesn't help much - it only highlights the questions having our favorite tag.

I wish to only look at hot questions posted in a particular tag, [python](/questions/tagged/python) for example. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

I recently discovered the way to view hot questions based on a particular tag... It is buried inside a couple of links. So follow the steps below to view all the hot answers in a particular tag, [python](/questions/tagged/python) in our example.

1. Visit the page of the tag, [python](/questions/tagged/python).
2. Here you would find the following tabs based on which questions may be listed. I know it's a little obscure, but click the [link for **info**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info).

   [image: question tabs for the tag]
3. In the right sidebar of this page, there is a section for **Recent Hot Answers**.

   [image: right sidebar in tag info]
4. Expanding the [**more** link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/hot) as seen in the previous image would take us to the page where we can further sort hot answers based on particular timeframe we want.

   [image: hot answers for particular tag]

I wish they could somehow incorporate the hot questions in the default page for tags along with all the tabs in the first image.

Comment: I was going to give you a +1 for this, but there's no freehand arrows and no unicorns.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Why not add some freehand arrows and unicorns as you wish :-)

Comment: I would, but I'm busy making waffles.